# Fragment's Context gets "lost" while passing it as a parameter

Tags: android

I came across a very awkward behaviour in my fragment. 
The output is:

```
this.userID: 0
```

and

```
RoomChatFragment userID: 14
```

But in this case, this.userID should also be 14. Is my context lost somewhere, while passing it as a parameter? I can't explain myself this behaviour. I don't think `getActivity()` returns `null`, otherwise there would be an exception.

```
    // Fragment
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        context = getActivity();
        user = new UserHandler(context);
        messageDatabase = MessageDatabase.getInstance(context);
        Log.i("debug", "RoomChatFragment userID: " + user.getUserID());
    }

// UserHandler
public class UserHandler {
    private final SharedPreferences sharedPrefs;
    private final SharedPreferences sharedPrefsPreferences;
    private Context context;

    public UserHandler(Context context) {
        sharedPrefs = context.getSharedPreferences("USER", 0);
        sharedPrefsPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public int getUserID() {
        return sharedPrefs.getInt("userID", 0);
    }

    public void setUserID(int userID) {
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("userID", userID);
        editor.apply();
    }
}

// Database
public class MessageDatabase extends AbstractDatabase {
    private int userID;
    protected static MessageDatabase instance;

    public MessageDatabase(Context context) {
        super(context);
        UserHandler user = new UserHandler(context);
        userID = user.getUserID();
    }

    public static MessageDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
        if (MessageDatabase.instance == null) {
            MessageDatabase.instance = new MessageDatabase(context);
        }

        return MessageDatabase.instance;
    }

    // ....

    @Override
    protected Message cursorToObject(Cursor cursor) {
        Log.i("debug", "this.userID: " + this.userID);
    }
}

// AbstractDatabase
public abstract class AbstractDatabase {
    protected Context context;

    protected AbstractDatabase(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

Comment: Show how you save it please

Comment: Do you see the same behavior if you change `editor.apply();` to `editor.commit();`

Comment: `this.userID:` is set on construction, while `RoomChatFragment userID:` is queried from the preference object. The value may not have been changed yet during construction of the `MessageDatabase` object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stupid me! The problem is the **singleton design pattern** of my database design. My `MessageDatabase.instance` is cached and holds an old `Context` object, where the `userID` of my `SharedPreferences` is 0.

I've updated my method like this and it seems to work:

```
public static MessageDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
    if (MessageDatabase.instance == null || userID == 0) {
        MessageDatabase.instance = new MessageDatabase(context);
    }

    return MessageDatabase.instance;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not absolutely sure what's going on here (your code is really messy). But it seems you're using a different key for the preference:

```
context.getSharedPreferences("USER", 0);
sharedPrefs.getInt("userID", 0);
```

Comment: `USER` is the name of the preference file. `userID` is a key in the file. I obviously have a `setUserID()` method, which is called before. Edited my question.